# cakephp 2.5 slow response time

Tags: php, mysql, performance, cakephp

Ive got this function:

```
public function index() {
    $this->set('var', $this->Model->find('all'));
}
```

This action takes more than 3 seconds to be finished. When i commented out the find (query), it took only 0.02 sec. I already tried to set debug to 0 - didnt help. I found that only the first query takes so long to execute, any other query is finished below 0.01sec. I know that cakephp is creating object when calling the database first time and i already debugged that THATS what takes so long to process.

Now my question is : How is that possible that when i execute index from localhost it takes only 0.03 sec but when i do the same on remote server it takes more than 3 seconds? The server is not old nor slow itself and has good processor and RAM. I already tried to set set global innodb_stats_on_metadata=0; but it didnt help too.

Please guys i really need better response time than 3 seconds to simple query. I really need help from you.

Comment: How many records do you have on localhost and on remote? Approximately

Comment: On the exact Model i got 15 records on both localhost and on remote.

Comment: I already tried to put sql command inside phpmyadmin on localhost and remote. The result took about only 0.02sec on both of them. I dont think that it has to do something with the database itself but the creation of cakephp db object.

Comment: Have you checked the PHP version? maybe some extensions are missing?

Comment: Remote PHP Version 5.3.28-1~dotdeb.0 . Localhost PHP Version 5.5.12. What could be the possible missing extensions when the cakephp is working without error, just is slower?

Comment: Use a tool like [**XDebug**](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler) and start with figuring where _exactly_ the time is actually spent.

Comment: ... and you can also use [DebugKit](https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit) for a analysis within your CakePHP installation. Please note that there are different versions available for Cake 2 and 3...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well guys Im so happy i figured it out with some help. The problem was in the `app/config/database.php`
The file looked like this :

```
public $default = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'db.domain.com',
    'login' => 'login',
    'password' => 'password',
    'database' => 'database',
    'prefix' => '',
    'encoding' => 'utf8'
);
```

When i changed host to 'localhost' like this :

```
public $default = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => 'login',
    'password' => 'password',
    'database' => 'database',
    'prefix' => '',
    'encoding' => 'utf8'
);
```

suddenly the creation of mysql object reduced from more than 4 seconds to 0.03 second. I still cant believe it and i would appreciate if anybody could tell my why is there such a big difference, but this little change helped me with my problem. I hope it will help somebody too.

Comment: You seem to have a *super* slow DNS server - it needs to look up `db.domain.com` which for whatever reason takes a long time. This can be fixed by adding the domain to the hosts file (to avoid DNS resolving).

Answer (score 0):

Redrif, I would normally suggest Pagination, but based on the fact that you are only retrieving 15 records, you probably want to look into limiting /removing the amount of associated data being retrieved.

Use this to remove all associated data:

`$this->set('var', $this->Model->find('all', array('recursive' => -1)));`

Comment: Nope this was not the problem. But thank you for your answer.